# How to remove search on Site and leave only search on Content?

Tags: search

[image]How to remove search on Site and leave only search on Content? When I use search on Site it says "Search is temporarily unavailable. If the problem persists, please contact the site administrator". When I search on Contents, it is OK.

Answer (score 3):

So you are trying to make sure that the core Search only searches for content? if so you can tweak the core Search module at /admin/config/search/settings.

Comment: it is a custom search module, what settings to change?

Comment: Depends on which custom Search Module it is. Which one is it?

Comment: Google custom search